# Undefined index from a foreach() loop

Tags: php, mysql

ItemDb class

```
    public function getRandomItem() {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `items` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
        return $this->query($query);

    }
```

Index.php

```
    $item = new Item();

    $result = $item->getRandomItem();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
          //I want to put them in a array but the two items need to be separated 
       }
    }
```

I get two different items out of the database how can I split them and put them in one array separated like:

$array[$key][$value]

Sorry for my English its my second language and I hope you guys understand me.

Comment: You don't define `itemArray` before you use it. `$itemArray[$key]` doesn't exist before you try to append to it.

Comment: You are trying to write to `$itemArray`, but you have not declared it yet.  Then you are trying to add to its keys, but those values are not yet set.  PHP will let you do this, but as you can see it yells at you about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare `$itemArray[$key]` before you use it.  So your code needs to look like

```
$itemArray = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        if(!isset($itemArray[$key])) {
            $itemArray[$key] = array(); //Declare it
        }
        $itemArray[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work.  It's gonna re-assign `$itemArray[$key]` to a blank array each time.  Also, why `.= $value`?

Comment: He only adds one item from the database i want two items in one array is that possible?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Good point, I edited my code example

Comment: Omg it works!!! You made my day, can you explain what i did wrong?